# Forward master to to tag

Tags: git

- I commited to master
- I created a tag for this commit using `git tag -v v1.7 -m "foo"`
- I checked out a tag `git checkout v1.7` (master is pointing to the same commit ID)
- Then I created a commit
- Then I tagged this commit using `git tag -v v1.8 -m "bar"`

**How do I get master to be at the same commit ID as the tag `v1.8`**

Comment: why do you checkout v1.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get master to be at the same commit ID as the tag v1.8

If there were no new commits on `master` while you created `v1.8`,
then you can switch to it and merge from `v1.8` to get `master` fast-forwarded to `v1.8`:

```
git checkout master
git merge v1.8
```

Comment: It is the natural thing to do. I should just have tried it without posting here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a new branch from `v1.8`. Then create Pull request & merge the branch into `master`.

```
$ git checkout v1.8
$ git checkout -b branch1.8
$ git push origin HEAD      # push branch1.8 to remote
```

Create Pull request and merge it with `master` Or, you can directly merge `branch1.8` into `master` like:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin branch1.8    # fetch + merge 'branch1.8' into 'master'

$ git push origin master
```